# Ruby model find or create architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm creating a model with file information, but if there is such file (that checked by file hash) I should return existing file model. But I want to know in controller, does it new or not. I guess i could return array which contains model and boolean variable of existing model, but its ugly solution.

Perhaps I should move the part is uploading file to another module or something, but the data that extracting in this process is almost all model fields, and i don't want to return it from that module, then checking existing file model and creating it if it's new. But perhaps this is the right way.

Model:

```
class SourceFileInfo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :ext, type: String
  field :path, type: String
  field :original_name, type: String
  field :hash, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :hash
  validates_presence_of :name, :path

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book_info

  def self.find_or_create_from_params file_params, user
    # collect file data - name, ext, path
    require 'securerandom'
    original_name = file_params.original_filename

    directory = Rails.root.join("upload")
    file_id = SecureRandom.hex
    ext = original_name.split('.').last

    fb2_file_name = "#{file_id}.#{ext}"

    file_path = File.join(directory, fb2_file_name)
    File.open(file_path, "wb") { |f| f.write(file_params.read) }

    # check file exists in db and return it if it does
    require 'digest/md5'
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read file_path)
    return SourceFileInfo.where(hash: hash).first if SourceFileInfo.where(hash: hash).exists?

    # else return new model
    create(name: file_id, ext: ext, path: file_path,
           original_name: original_name, user: user)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
  def upload_book
    file_info = SourceFileInfo.find_or_create_from_params(file_params[:file], current_user)

    BookFileWorker.perform_async file_info.id.to_s

    render nothing: true
  end
```

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override the `find_or_create` method as it already exists and does what you want.

Instead of generating the hash in the model as you are now, why not use something like the following in your controller:

```
def upload_book
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(file_path))
    file_info = SourceFileInfo.find_or_initialize(hash: hash)
    if file_info.new_record?
        ... fill in other info and save record
    else
        ... do whatever else
    end 
end
```

Then your model can be cleaned up by removing the `find_or_create_from_params` method.

Comment: I did not the same but the `new_record?` helps me. I replace `create` on `new` and `save` if it's new. Thanks!

Comment: About your solution - i can't get hash so fast, cause first i should save file, it transfers by parts, and before save i should change the name, because it may exists. So that what 7 lines does. It's perhaps could be another method, but in this case it will return 3 variables, that involved in creation. But i could use hash and simply pass it in `find_or_initialize` method. I'll try to do this and compare this solutions.